# manual start nginx ,it ok with static html, but use systemctl start nginx, it's 403

Tags: nginx

`nginx version: nginx/1.19.0`

My nginx conf is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  root;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" ' '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'  ' query_string=$query_string' ' port=$upstream_http_port' ' b=$arg_b';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
          listen 10001;
          server_name test1;
          location / {
             root /home/static/;
             index index.html;
          }
      }

}
```

my html file is

```sh
$ cat /home/static/index.html
hello
```

```sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6 2021-10-07 05:38:24 static/index.html
```

when I start nginx manual,it's work .

```sh
$ nginx && curl localhost:10001
hello
```

but when I start by systemctl

```sh
$ systemctl start nginx && curl localhost:10001
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

the nginx.service status like this

```sh
$ systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-10-07 07:34:00 CST; 1min 23s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 13951 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c /bin/kill -s TERM $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid) (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 14184 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14185 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─14185 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
           └─14186 nginx: worker process

Oct 07 07:34:00 centos7 systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Oct 07 07:34:00 centos7 systemd[1]: Started nginx - high performance web server.
```

here is my nginx.service configuration

```sh
cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=http://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c "/bin/kill -s HUP $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid)"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "/bin/kill -s TERM $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid)"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who has SELinux == Enforcing and Nginx returns 403 for static files :

Enable SELinux httpdcannetwork_connect feature

```sh
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

check SELinux enforce

```sh
getenforce
```

If it is Enforcing -

```
chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_t /home/static/
```